# Thickness of lines in Package ‘treemap’

Tags: r

The Package ‘tree map’ allows to plot hierarchical tree maps.

The thickness of the intersection lines cannot be customized according the [cran documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/treemap.pdf).
I'd like to make them a bit thicker to really make sure that hierarchies are visible.

Any trick to modify the lines thickness?

Comment: Code, data. Post an example to work with.

Comment: One simple solution would be to specify the thickness of lines using the `par()` function. For instance, you can try `lwd=2`. A more complex solution would be to look at the code of the `treemap()` (`page(treemap)`) function and find the parameter which specifies the line width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for using the treemap package.

Adjusting line thickness is not yet implemented in treemap, but I will include it in the next version.

A workaround for now is:

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2010)
treemap(GNI2010,
         index=c("continent", "iso3"),
         vSize="population",
         vColor="GNI",
         type="value")

library(grid)
getNames() #get all grid object names
grid.edit("Africa", gp=gpar(lwd=4))
```

**UPDATE**
It is already included in dev. version on https://github.com/mtennekes/treemap. See argument lwds.

Comment: CRAN until now seems not to have updated it's library with the new line thickness feature.

Answer (score 1):

Get the development version of treemap (currently version 2.1):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("treemap", username="mtennekes", subdir="pkg")
library(treemap)
```

Next define linewidth using border.lwds (not lwds).

```
data(business) # in treemap
treemap(business,
    index=c(paste0("NACE",1:3)),
    vSize="employees",
    vColor="NACE1",
    type="categorical",
    border.col = c("red","white"), # defines line colour 
    border.lwds = c(1,3), # defines line width
    position.legend = "none") # remove legend
```